# Show values by selecting them in a tableview firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I would really appreciate it if you could help me!
Create a tableview showing my firebase database values:
[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwSOY.png)

What I need is that when selecting the table cell, show in the view controller the data depending on the selected cell.
This is the function when selecting the cell and correctly prints the name:

```
var listAccount = [modelAccount]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
     let account = listAccount[indexPath.row]
     print(account.name!)
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountViewController", sender: UIButton())

}
```

This is the model:

```
class modelAccount {

     var id:String?
     var number: String?
     var name: String?

     init(id: String?, number: String?, name: String?){
         self.id = id
         self.number = number
         self.name = name
     }

}
```

Here I want to show the data obtained:
[Account ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFyJw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountViewController", sender: UIButton())
```

with

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountViewController", sender: account)
```

and implement

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.idemtifier == "accountViewController" {
       let accountViewController = segue.destination as! AccountViewController
       let account = sender as! ModelAccount // class names should start with an uppercase letter
       // assign account to something in accountViewController
    }
}
```